# Is there a way to optimize this script so that it runs more efficiently?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

I wrote a script that creates a new Active Directory user, creates a mailbox in a hybrid exchange environment, and then licenses Office 365 for the user. My script runs fine, but I'm trying to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this. One issue I am running in to is when I am creating the mailbox and licensing the user it keeps prompting me to login using my AD credentials for "MSOL-connect"... Obviously I have this in a loop and I understand that, but is there a way to only load it once without it continuously asking me for each user?

```
CLS

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function CreateADUser
{
    #Install the module that will let us to perform certain tasks in Excel
    #Install PSExcel Module for powershell
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ImportExcel) 
    {
            #Write-Host "Module exists"
    } 
    else 
    {
        Install-Module -Name ImportExcel
    }

    Import-Module ImportExcel

    <#
        The worksheet variable will need to be modified before running this script. 
        Whatever the name of the worksheetis that you want to import data from, type that in below.
    #>
    $worksheet = "May"

    #The file we will be reading from
    $ExcelFile = (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\test.xlsx"

    $Import = Import-Excel -Path $ExcelFile -WorkSheetname $worksheet -StartRow 3

    #Grab all the information for each individual user and store it in an array. (start with row 4, because that's where user information is listed)
    foreach ($User in $Import)
    {
        $DisplayName = $User."Name"

        #Get First Name
        $FirstName = ($User."Name" -split " ")[0]

        #Get Last Name
        $LastName = ($User."Name" -split " ")[1]

        #Get UserName (initial of first name and last name)
        $Username = $FirstName[0]+$LastName

        #Set new aduser password
        $UserPassword = "P@55W0rD!@#"

        #Email Address
        $Email = $Username+"@blah.com"

        #The profile we are copying from
        $CopiedProfile = $($User."Copy Similar To")        
        #$CopiedProfileUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -eq $CopiedProfile } -Properties memberof
        $CopiedProfileUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -eq $CopiedProfile } -Properties *
        #$CopiedProfileUser

        #Check to see if the new account we're going to create already exists
        $validate = Get-ADUser -Filter { sAMAccountName -like $Username }
        #$validate

        If($validate -eq $Null) 
        {
            #User does not exist in AD, create the account

           #Fill in the fields for our new user
            $CopiedProfileUser | ForEach-Object{
                $userprops=@{
                    Name=$DisplayName
                    SamAccountName=$Username
                    Surname=$LastName
                    GivenName=$FirstName
                    DisplayName=$DisplayName
                    Department=$_.Department
                    Description=$_.Description
                    EmployeeNumber=$_.employeeNumber
                    EmployeeID=$_.employeeID
                    Office=$_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                    City=$_.City
                    l=$_.l
                    Manager=$_.Manager
                    State=$_.st
                    StreetAddress=$_.streetAddress
                    Company=$_.company
                    PostalCode=$_.PostalCode
                    Title=$_.Title
                    UserPrincipalName=$Email
                    Path=$_.DistinguishedName -replace '^cn=.+?(?<!\\),'
                    AccountPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $UserPassword -AsPlainText -Force
                    Enabled=$_.Enabled
                }
                New-ADUser @userprops
            }
            #$userprops

            $CopiedProfileUser.memberof | add-adgroupmember -members $Username

            #Add to the Dynamic Distribution Group
            Set-ADUser –Identity $Username -Clear "extensionAttribute2"
            Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Add @{ extensionAttribute2 = "DynamicDistro" }

            Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Add @{ co = "USA" }
            Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Add @{ msExchRecipLimit = $CopiedProfileUser.msExchRecipLimit }
            Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Add @{ msExchUserAccountControl = $CopiedProfileUser.msExchUserAccountControl }
            Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Add @{ physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $CopiedProfileUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName }


            ############################################################
            ############################################################
            ############################################################
            ######                                                ###### 
            ######                                                ######
            ######                 Mail Setup                     ######
            ######                                                ######
            ######                                                ######
            ############################################################
            ############################################################
            ############################################################

            #Now we need to setup the mailbox for the new user
            if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ADSync) 
            {
                    #Write-Host "Module exists"
            } 
            else 
            {
                Install-Module -Name ADSync
            }

            #Check if the module is already running, if not, run it.
            If (!(Get-module ADSync)) 
            {
                Import-Module ADSync -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            }

            #Use the currently logged in session to authenticate
            $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://mailbox-server.mydomain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
            Import-PSSession $Session

            $mos = $Username + "@blah.mail.onmicrosoft.com"

            #This creates the mailbox
            Enable-RemoteMailbox $Username -RemoteRoutingAddress $mos

            ############################################################
            ############################################################
            ############################################################
            ######                                                ###### 
            ######                                                ######
            ######           License User in Office               ######
            ######                                                ######
            ######                                                ######
            ############################################################
            ############################################################
            ############################################################

            #Connect to the services we will need.
            #Connect-AzureAD
            Connect-MsolService

            Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $email -UsageLocation US
            Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $email -AddLicenses "blah:ENTERPRISEPACK"

            pause
        }
        Else
        {
            #$_.Exception | -filepath (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\error.xlsx"
            Write-Error "User Account already exists"
        }
    }
}


CreateADUser
```

Comment: It seems like all of the Set-ADUser commands could be done in one command with a single hash table using the -replace switch. The Get-ADUser filter should not be a scriptblock as I would change it to be inside of single quotes.

Comment: You should change the if statement condition from $validate -eq $null to $null -eq $validate because that is really your intention. If $validate ended up being an array, it may be possible for your condition to not be $true if the array contains a $null element along with non-nulls.

Comment: You should not need to pipe $CopiedProfileUser into ForEach-Object since you can only create one AD user no matter how many pipeline objects you have. samaccountname has to be unique in AD and that value comes from your outer loop. It seems you just want the current pipeline object $_. You could instead just use $CopiedProfileUser.property.

Comment: I think my suggestions above are valid but don’t address the significant annoyances of having to create an AD account, create a hybrid exchange account, wait for Azure sync, then wait for O365 backend replication that you have no control over, then assign licensing. If you have MFA on the account running these tasks, I would consider setting up an Azure conditional access policy to make life easier in a very limited scope. Maybe jobs could allow for more parallel processing if your user list is large.

Comment: You could also do all of the on-Prem AD and hybrid exchange tasks first for all users. Then do all of the Azure work after.

Comment: Thanks for the list of suggestions. I have done everything you have suggested. I'll try to come up with a plan for setting up the mailboxes and licensing maybe in a separate function... The thing is if I do it in a separate functions how can I push the variables from each new user to the mailbox setup function? 

For example, I would need to push the $email variable to the mail setup function.

Comment: I would suggest you to write an answer for the same and accept it as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create 2 parts to this script. The first part created the user and mailbox, then 2nd part licensed the user in Office 365, but I waited at least 30 mins before running the 2nd part.

Part 1

```
CLS

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function CreateADUser
{
    #Install the module that will let us to perform certain tasks in Excel
    #Install PSExcel Module for powershell
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name ImportExcel) 
    {
            #Write-Host "Module exists"
    } 
    else 
    {
        Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
        Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Force 
    }

    Import-Module ImportExcel

    <#
        The worksheet variable will need to be modified before running this script. 
        Whatever the name of the worksheetis that you want to import data from, type that in below.
    #>
    $worksheet = "Sheet1"

    #Remove the emails file if it already exists
    $EmailFile = (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\emails.txt"

    if([System.IO.File]::Exists($EmailFile))
    {
        remove-item $EmailFile -Force
    }

    #The file we will be reading from
    $ExcelFile = (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\NW Master.xlsx"
    #This will be where we write errors to
    $ErrorFile = (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\ERROR.txt"

    $Import = Import-Excel -Path $ExcelFile -WorkSheetname $worksheet -StartRow 1

    #Grab all the information for each individual user and store it in an array. (start with row 1, because that's where user information is listed)
    foreach ($User in $Import)
    {
        #Get Display name
        $DisplayName = $User."Full Name"

        #Get First Name
        $FirstName = $User."First Name"

        #Get Last Name
        $LastName = $User."Last"

        #Username
        $Username = ($FirstName[0] + $LastName)

        #If Username has any spaces, then remove the space
        if($Username -like "* *")
        {
            $Username = $Username -replace " ",""
        }

        #Set new aduser password
        $UserPassword = "Password123!@#"

        $OfficeLocation = $user."Office Location"

        #The profile we are copying from
        $CopiedProfile = $($User."Modeled Profile")        
        $CopiedProfileUser = Get-ADUser -Filter 'DisplayName -eq $CopiedProfile' -Properties *

        #Check to see if the new account we're going to create already exists
        $validate = Get-ADUser -Filter 'DisplayName -eq $DisplayName'

        #If($validate -eq $Null)
        If($Null -eq $validate) 
        {
            #Email Address
            $Email = $Username+"@domain.com"

            #We will output the emails to a file. We will need that for a later time
            $Email | Out-File -Append -FilePath $EmailFile

            Try
            {
                #User does not exist in AD, create the account

                $userprops=@{
                    Name=$DisplayName
                    SamAccountName=$Username
                    Surname=$LastName
                    GivenName=$FirstName
                    DisplayName=$DisplayName
                    Department=$CopiedProfileUser.Department
                    Description=$CopiedProfileUser.Description
                    EmployeeNumber=$CopiedProfileUser.employeeNumber
                    EmployeeID=$CopiedProfileUser.employeeID
                    Office=$CopiedProfileUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                    City=$CopiedProfileUser.City
                    l=$CopiedProfileUser.l
                    Manager=$CopiedProfileUser.Manager
                    State=$CopiedProfileUser.st
                    StreetAddress=$CopiedProfileUser.streetAddress
                    Company=$CopiedProfileUser.company
                    PostalCode=$CopiedProfileUser.PostalCode
                    Title=$CopiedProfileUser.Title
                    UserPrincipalName=$Email
                    Path=$CopiedProfileUser.DistinguishedName -replace '^cn=.+?(?<!\\),'
                    AccountPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $UserPassword -AsPlainText -Force
                    Enabled=$True
                }

                New-ADUser @userprops

                #Add the user group memberships from the copied profile
                $CopiedProfileUser.memberof | add-adgroupmember -members $Username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                #Add to the Dynamic Distribution attribute and other AD attributes
                Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Replace @{ extensionAttribute2 = "DynamicDistro"; co = "USA"; physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $OfficeLocation }
            }
            Catch
            {
                $_.Exception.Message | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
                $_.Exception.ItemName | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
                $_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
                $_.ErrorDetails.Message | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
                $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
                $_.CategoryInfo.ToString() | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
                $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile
            }
        }
        Else
        {
            #If the username exists, use the first 2 characters of their first name
            $UsernameModified = (($FirstName.Substring(0,2))+$LastName) 

            #If UsernameModified has any spaces, then remove the space
            if($UsernameModified -like "* *")
            {
                $UsernameModified = $UsernameModified -replace " ",""
            }

            #Email Address
            $EmailModified = $UsernameModified+"@domain.com"

            #We will output the emails to a file. We will need that for a later time
            $EmailModified | Out-File -Append -FilePath $EmailFile

            #User already exists, so lets get some info
            Write-output "User $Username Full Name: $DisplayName already exists in AD: " $validate | Out-File -Append -FilePath $ErrorFile

             $userprops=@{
                    Name=$DisplayName
                    SamAccountName=$UsernameModified
                    Surname=$LastName
                    GivenName=$FirstName
                    DisplayName=$DisplayName
                    Department=$CopiedProfileUser.Department
                    Description=$CopiedProfileUser.Description
                    EmployeeNumber=$CopiedProfileUser.employeeNumber
                    EmployeeID=$CopiedProfileUser.employeeID
                    Office=$CopiedProfileUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
                    City=$CopiedProfileUser.City
                    l=$CopiedProfileUser.l
                    Manager=$CopiedProfileUser.Manager
                    State=$CopiedProfileUser.st
                    StreetAddress=$CopiedProfileUser.streetAddress
                    Company=$CopiedProfileUser.company
                    PostalCode=$CopiedProfileUser.PostalCode
                    Title=$CopiedProfileUser.Title
                    UserPrincipalName=$EmailModified
                    Path=$CopiedProfileUser.DistinguishedName -replace '^cn=.+?(?<!\\),'
                    AccountPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString -String $UserPassword -AsPlainText -Force
                    Enabled=$True
                }

                New-ADUser @userprops

                #Add the user group memberships from the copied profile
                $CopiedProfileUser.memberof | add-adgroupmember -members $UsernameModified -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                #Add to the Dynamic Distribution attribute and other AD attributes
                Set-ADUser -Identity $UsernameModified -Replace @{ extensionAttribute2 = "DynamicDistro"; co = "USA"; physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $OfficeLocation }
        }
    }
}

Function CreateMailBox
{

    #Import the sync module we will need

    #Check if we have a session open right now
    $SessionsRunning = get-pssession

    if($SessionsRunning.ComputerName -like "*aad-sync-srvr*")
    {
        #If session is running we don't need to do anything
    }
    else
    {
        #If session isn't running, lets start it
        $AADsession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "aad-sync-srvr.domain.com"
        Invoke-Command -Session $AADsession -ScriptBlock {Import-Module -Name 'ADSync'}
    }

    #Sync our changes with AD
    Invoke-Command -Session $AADsession -ScriptBlock {Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta}

    #Sleep for a minute to make sure the sync finishes
    Start-Sleep -s 60

    if($SessionsRunning.ComputerName -like "*mbx-srvr*")
    {
        #If session is running we don't need to do anything
    }
    else
    {
        #If session isn't running, lets start it
        $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://mbx-srvr.domain.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
        Import-PSSession $Session
    }

    #Now lets read the emails from the emails.txt file and create the mailboxes for the new users
    $EmailFile = (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\emails.txt"

    Get-Content $EmailFile | ForEach-Object {
        $useremail = $_
        $userprefix = ($useremail -split "@")[0]
        $mos = $userprefix + "@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com"

        Enable-RemoteMailbox $userprefix -RemoteRoutingAddress $mos
    }

    #Sleep for a minute to make sure the sync finishes
    Start-Sleep -s 60

    #Run the sync once more
    Invoke-Command -Session $AADsession -ScriptBlock {Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta}

   # Remove-PSSession $Session
    Remove-PSSession $AADsession
}

#Create the new user
CreateADUser

#Create the mailbox
CreateMailBox
```

Part 2

```
CLS

Function LicenseOfficeUser
{
    if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name MSOnline) 
    {
            #Write-Host "Module exists"
    } 
    else 
    {
        Install-Module -Name MSOnline -Force 
    }

    #Quick way to see if we are connected to the MSOL service is to run a simple query. If it doesn't return NULL, then we are fine and don't need to load it again
    if(!(Get-MsolUser -SearchString "Some AD User" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
    {
        $creds = Get-Credential
        Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds
    }

    $EmailFile = (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) + "\emails.txt"
    $license = (Get-MsolAccountSku).AccountSkuId | Where-Object {$_ -like "domain:ENTERPRISEPACK" }

    #Now lets read the emails from the emails.txt file and create the mailboxes for the new users
    Get-Content $EmailFile | ForEach-Object {
        $useremail = $_
        $LicenseOptions = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuID $license

        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $useremail -UsageLocation 'US' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $useremail -AddLicenses $license -LicenseOptions $LicenseOptions -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

#License the User in Office
LicenseOfficeUser
```

Hope users find this useful